# AngularJS: How to check what is causing my page to get unloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Due to a PC crash, my project has lost some unsaved code and I am running to different errors. One of them being that on clicking on any anchor tag on the page, I can see the function for ng-click is called but also at the end page navigates to server-base path. I have no clue what causes this navigation and I am trying to find out. How can I debug to find out what is causing this page unload/ navigation? Is there any defined rule for angular that makes it go to default path if something goes wrong?
On the debug console, I can see the following highlighted network request made about which I have no clue [image] 
[image]

What does 'Other' as the request source mean? The GetSourceList calls specifies that angularjs called it, but what about the requests tagged as others?

Comment: post at least some code

Comment: There is `otherwise` in the route definition if the path is not found but your issue seems to be something else.

Comment: Can you provide your Angular.js router code please?

Comment: I am not using any routing. I need a way to figure out how to track the source of unload event. On the click handler, I also tried with event.preventDefault(), but that didnt help too

Comment: What does the console returns ?

Comment: I have added few network call images in the question. Can you all please take a look?